# Virtual Mac XCode iPhone debugging - device not connected issue

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, virtual-machine

Please bear with the question (I know there are many repeats but I am sure this is unique) and read this first before you think of downvoting due to duplicity:

- This is pertaining to iPhone connected to my local desktop and XCode running on remote VM
- The [USB gate software](http://www.eltima.com/products/usb-over-network-mac/) is connecting my iPhone to the VM
- It's not that XCode fails to detect it altogether.
- It's an iPhone 3GS running iOS 5.1. XCode version is 4.6.

**Now the issue:**

I have the iPhone UDID added to my Apple developer Profile.

I can very well detect the iphone connected into XCode once I do all the necessary sharing for the USB Gate software. I see the yellow light.

It shows yellow light, shows some of the apps installed while some process is running in background. It shows the UDID and usual stuff.

After few moments though, XCode displays the message `Device not connected`.

I have already added support for armv6 inside my app, so that possibility is ruled out.

What to do?

PS: for the first time it launched iTunes after detection. However then onwards I disabled auto-syncing from iTunes. And now iTunes doesn't detect it even if I launch it explicitly. XCode does detect it, but after some time disconnects it automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I successfully connected to remote VM installing [Logmein's Hamachi VPN software](https://secure.logmein.com/products/hamachi/) on both my host and VM. Using it, XCode could detect my iPhone device once shared via [USB Network Gate](http://www.eltima.com/products/usb-over-network-mac/).

Comment: If XCode on a Virtual MAchine  doesn't see your device try changing your USB in VM setings from 3.0 to 2.0. I helped in my case https://superuser.com/questions/981711/virtualized-osx-cant-see-iphone-device